# How to find two months old password users in a Windows domain?

Tags: windows, password, active-directory, search

how can I search for two or three months old passwords on a Windows domain controller?

I am an administrator on this domain.

Comment: Its difficult to determine what your after, are you looking to retrieve a list of users who's passwords will be expiring, or do you want to find out what a users password was 2-3 months ago?

Comment: i want to find out what a users password was 2-3 months ago?

Comment: You could accept the answer now. This way it's clear that it is the right answer to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

> dsquery user -stalepwd 60

Returns a list of all users with a password age of 60 days or more.

Comment: Kara mafia 

This is what i want exactly ..Thank you so much  for kind help

Answer (score 3):

have a look at this artice from the microsoft scripting guys

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/nov08/hey1118.mspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're asking for. But take a look at [dsquery.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732952(WS.10).aspx), which can retrieve many interesting things from an Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveDirectory extension to PowerShell GUI will also provide an extensive list of fields when exporting to CSV a list of AD users including password expiration

Comment: Finally i am expert to generate the reports on AD now .thanks to everyone guys .really i was learned this from here all